# Timezone conversion in java

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I am implementing the following method-

```
DateTime getDateTime(Date srcDate, String destTimeZone) {
}
```

As the input is of `Date` object, I can safely assume the timezone of it as "UTC". I have to convert it to `destTimeZone` and return `DateTime` object.

Any pointers in an efficient way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Such a method is not really hard to implement with Joda Time:

```
public DateTime getDateTime( Date srcDate, String destTimeZone )
{
    return new DateTime( srcDate, DateTimeZone.forID( destTimeZone) );
}
```

The standard Java way would be:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance( TimeZone.getTimeZone( destTimeZone ) );
cal.setTimeInMillis( srcDate.getTime() );
// now you have a Calendar object with time zone set
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime getDateTime(Date srcDate, String destTimeZone) {

    return new DateTime(new Date(srcDate.getTime() + 
                   TimeZone.getTimeZone(destTimeZone).getRawOffset()));

}
```

Comment: This doesn't give correct results for timezones that can switch to daylight saving time and back and it would confuse Joda since it expects a Date to be always in UTC/GMT as usual in Java.